# Fill with the values from neighbor value compering other column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having dataframe like this:

```
azimuth   id
15        100
15        1     
15        100
150       2
150       100
240       3
240       100
240       100
350       100
```

What I need is to fill instead 100 values values from row where azimuth is the closest:
Desired output:

```
azimuth      id
    15        1
    15        1     
    15        1
    150       2
    150       2
    240       3
    240       3
    240       3
    350       1
```

350 is near to 15 because this is a circle (angle representation). The difference is 25.

What I have:

```
def mysubstitution(x):
    for i in x.index[x['id'] == 100]:
        i = int(i)
        diff = (x['azimuth'] - x.loc[i, 'azimuth']).abs()
        for ind in diff.index:
            if diff[ind] > 180:
                diff[ind] = 360 - diff[ind]
            else:
                pass
        exclude = [y for y in x.index if y not in x.index[x['id'] == 100]]
        closer_idx = diff[exclude]
        closer_df = pd.DataFrame(closer_idx)
        sorted_df = closer_df.sort_values('azimuth', ascending=True)
        try:
            a = sorted_df.index[0]
            x.loc[i, 'id'] = x.loc[a, 'id']
        except Exception as a:
            print(a)
    return x
```

Which works ok most of the time, but I guess there is some simpler solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you already have the id columns (which seems to be the hard part), can you `df['id'] % 100 + 1`

Comment: @Kenan Not sure I understand?

Comment: `except Exception as a: print(a)`is a bad practice for at least two reasons, be careful.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement the functionality in two steps. First, for each azimuth, I grouped another dataframe that holds their id value(for values other than 100).

Then, using this array I implemented the `replaceAzimuth` function, which takes each row in the dataframe, first checks if the value already exists. If so, it directly replaces it. Otherwise,it replaces the id value with the closest `azimuth` value from the grouped dataframe.

Here is the implementation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[15,100],[15,1],[15,100],[150,2],[150,100],[240,3],[240,100],[240,100],[350,100]],columns=['azimuth','id'])

df_non100 = df[df['id'] != 100]
df_grouped = df_non100.groupby(['azimuth'])['id'].min().reset_index()

def replaceAzimuth(df_grouped,id_val):
    real_id = df_grouped[df_grouped['azimuth'] == id_val['azimuth']]['id']
    if real_id.size == 0:
        df_diff = df_grouped
        df_diff['azimuth'] = df_diff['azimuth'].apply(lambda x: min(abs(id_val['azimuth'] - x),(360 - id_val['azimuth'] + x)))
        id_val['id'] = df_grouped.iloc[df_diff['azimuth'].idxmin()]['id']
    else:
        id_val['id'] = real_id
    return id_val


df = df.apply(lambda x: replaceAzimuth(df_grouped,x), axis = 1)

df
```

For me, the code seems to give the output you have shown. But not sure if will work on all cases!

Answer (score 1):

First set all ids to nan if they are 100.

```
df.id = np.where(df.id==100, np.nan, df.id)
```

Then calculate the angle diff pairwise and find the closest ID to fill the nans.

```
df.id = df.id.combine_first(
    pd.DataFrame(np.abs(((df.azimuth.values[:,None]-df.azimuth.values) +180) % 360 - 180))
    .pipe(np.argsort)
    .applymap(lambda x: df.id.iloc[x])
    .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0], axis=1)
)

df
    azimuth id
0   15      1.0
1   15      1.0
2   15      1.0
3   150     2.0
4   150     2.0
5   240     3.0
6   240     3.0
7   240     3.0
8   350     1.0
```